# mysql - sum number of occurrence of values in all rows and columns

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and stuck with a problem.

table A looks like this:

```
-------
A|B|C|D
-------
5|4|3|2
-------
1|2|3|2
-------
5|1|3|2
-------
2|4|3|5
-------
```

I want to sum all occurence of each value i.e 5 came 3 times, 3 came 4 times etc.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: How many different values can you have?  Only 1-5, or even more than this?

Comment: Normalise your schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A,COUNT(*) FROM (select A from tre UNION ALL 
   select B from tre UNION ALL
   select C from tre UNION ALL 
  select D from tre) X group by A; 
+------+----------+
| A    | COUNT(*) |
+------+----------+
|    1 |        2 |
|    2 |        5 |
|    3 |        4 |
|    4 |        2 |
|    5 |        3 |
+------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @NewDev Please mark this as answer else it will show as unanswered question